# Error 1155. No application is associated

Tags: c#, installation, windows-installer, setup-project

everyone.
I've made a setup project for my application in VS 2010.
In XP and WinServer 2008 the application is installed fine, but in Windows 7 it fails in the beginning of the installation with message: "ShellExecuteEx failed; code 1155. No application is associated with the specific file for this operation"

Proper MS Installer is installed on the machine, hh.exe in windows exists to, so .msi and .chm files opens correctly. I think the right question is what is the file type in the install pack that isn't associated with any application.

Any suggestions..?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you everyone. I've found the solution. That was an installer of a web project. Of course I turned IIS on to run it. But for Win 7 that is not enough - IIS 6 Management Compatibility must also be active. I hope, this post will help someone to avoid this error.